# How does ImageIO determine the dimension of images?

Tags: java, image-processing, arrays, javax.imageio

I downloaded a snipped of code that contains this line:

```
BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray))
```

where bytearray is of type byte[].

How does ImageIO.read know the dimensions of the image from a 1 dim byte array?
e.g. if bytearray is of length 30, how does it know if it's an image that's 3x10 or 5x6 or 1x30?

The entire source code is [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-image-to-byte-array-convert-byte-array-to-image/), look at "Method 2".

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;


public class SimpleConvertImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        String dirName="C:\\";
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream(1000);
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File(dirName,"rose.jpg"));
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();

        String base64String=Base64.encode(baos.toByteArray());
        baos.close();

        byte[] bytearray = Base64.decode(base64String);
            // *The following line*
        BufferedImage imag=ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
        ImageIO.write(imag, "jpg", new File(dirName,"snap.jpg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"How does ImageIO.read know the dimensions"*  By parsing the data contained in the stream.

Comment: does the byte array stores that information in its header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each image file format has it's own header. Typically, the width and height of an image are defined in the header of the file. ImageIO handles the data for you so you don't need to worry about it. If you want to know more details, check the specification for each image format.

[`PNG >> Header Specification`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)

---

Now, if you want to access the width and height of a BufferedImage, then try this

```
    ... //after getting a BufferedImage from ImageIO.read() and storing it into image
    int imageWidth = image.getWidth();
    int imageHeight = image.getHeight();
```

[`java.awt.image.BufferedImage#getWidth()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getWidth%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)

[`java.awt.image.BufferedImage#getHeight()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getHeight%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29)